# How to Vertically center a web-page?

Tags: html, css

I am making a photography website, the size of page is about 960x780, and i want the page to remain in the center (vertically and horizontally) of the window, wether we zoom in or out of the page.

I tried, but I'm facing problems with positioning.

Can anyone please tell me the answer?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `position: absolute;` to bring your page, better to describe it as a div/container in center horizontally/vertically...

Like This

```
.center {
   width: 960px;
   height: 780px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   margin-left: -480px; /* Half of the total width */
   margin-top: -390px; /* Half of the total height */
}
```

and if you want to center it just **vertically** you can do it like this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainwrapper">
   <div class="innerwrap">
      <div class="content">
        Your content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainwrapper {
    display:table;
}

.innerwrap {
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: This works well unless the viewer's screen is smaller than 960 x 780px.  How would you handle a situation where the screen was smaller?

Comment: @VictorKilo than go for the second option :)