# Align 3 divs horizontally centered and linkable?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've spent a few hours with this, and I think it's much simpler to do this.. I'm trying to center 3 divs horizontally whilst keeping them fully linkable, and I finally gave up on that and tried tables ( :-o )

The first one shows my failed attempt at linking a div.

```
 <center><table>
    <tr>

    <td>
    <a href="http://google.com" style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%">
    <div>
    a
    </div>
    </a>
    </td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

With CSS

```
tbody tr td{
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
border: 2px solid #000;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.7;
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
font-family: 'calibri'; //temporary
padding: 30px;
}
body center table
{
border-spacing: 20px;
margin-top: -90px;
}
tr td a{
height:150%;
width:150%;
}
```

If anyone knows how to do this with divs or tables, your responses are greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can read this answer of mine as a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757135/how-to-vertically-center-a-web-page/12757198#12757198

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use `table`s at all. The key here is `display: inline-block;`. See it in action here: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/GGbtd/). HTML:

```
<div class = "onediv"><a href = "#">Glee is awesome!</a></div>
<div class = "onediv"><a href = "#">Glee is awesome!</a></div>
<div class = "onediv"><a href = "#">Glee is awesome!</a></div>​
```

CSS:

```
body { /*this should be whatever is containing your three divs*/
    text-align: center; /*center them*/
    white-space: nowrap; /*make sure they're all on the same line*/
}
.onediv {
    display: inline-block; /*magic*/
    height: 200px; /*or whatever you want*/
    width: 150px;
    /*make it look pretty*/
    background: rgb(0, 162, 232);
    color: white;
}
a {
    color: white;
    height: 100%; /*spans the whole div vertically*/
    width: 100%; /*and horizontally (not necessary, but can't hurt!)*/
    display: block; /*otherwise the height and width definitions won't work*/
}​
```

Comment: Do you really need `height` and `width` with `display:block` on `a`s? Is it because of `inline-block` on the parent?

Comment: @GionaF Nope, it isn't about that. He wants the whole `div` to be fully clickable. And normally `height` and `width` don't work on `a`s, because they're `inline` by default.

Comment: Yup, but with `display:block` they should fit the whole space anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @GionaF Yes, horizontally, but not vertically :)

Comment: Ok :) i thought it was an issue with `inline-block`, usually i don't go for it. Good answer anyway, both our answers "need" a fallback for IE7, but yours is easier. +1

Comment: AHH, thank you @Abody97 - this is lovely! I'll be using it a lot in the future!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/emWuu/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div><a href="#">a</a></div>
<div><a href="#">b</a></div>
<div><a href="#">c</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper, #wrapper * {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:1020px; /* width of divs + margin */
}
#wrapper > div {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:20px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    line-height:140px; /* optional, will center the text vertically */
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'calibri';
    padding: 30px;
}
#wrapper > div a {
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

​
​**Edit**: updated with your styling

Comment: Thank you @GionaF! This is quite an intelligent solution. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>
<a href="http://google.com" style="display:block;height:100%;width:100%">
<div>
a
</div>
</a>
</td>
```

You make all `td`s `div` lining.